# SimpleMessageListenerContainer - recover from failure

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-amqp, helix

What would be the easiest way to shut down SimpleMessageListenerContainer (created programatically, not as bean) on any possible error (missing queue, connection problem, etc.), and create new one (with re-declaring all the bindings in the run time.

I'm using helix for partition management, and have 1 listener per partition. One possibility would be also to use existing SimpleMessageListenerContainer (not to always create new one), but in this case, I would need to retry queue re-declaration and rebinding in case of any failure.

Also, there seems to be different kinds of exceptions - fatal (eg queue deleted in runtime) and non fatal (connection lost). How to handle both situations at once?

What would be easier option of these two?

**UPDATED**

```
private Map<SimpleMessageListenerContainer, AtomicBoolean> shuttingDown = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent listenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent) {

    boolean fatal = listenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent.isFatal();
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer)listenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent.getSource();

    if(fatal){
        AtomicBoolean sd = shuttingDown
                .computeIfAbsent(listenerContainer, v -> new AtomicBoolean(false));
        if(sd.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            System.out.println("RECREATING");
            String[] qn = listenerContainer.getQueueNames();
            String q = qn[0];
            recreateQueue(q);
            listenerContainer.stop();
            listenerContainer.start();
            //delete from shuttingDown ?
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("RECREATING_NOT");
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("NON_FATAL");
    }
}
```

and the output

```
NON_FATAL
NON_FATAL
NON_FATAL
NON_FATAL
22:36:44.044 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-7] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Consumer received fatal=false...\
...

RECREATING
RECREATING_NOT
RECREATING_NOT
RECREATING_NOT
22:36:44.057 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Stopping container from aborted consumer
```

Comment: What is the reason for re-creating the SimpleMessageListenerContainer bean in case of a failure? Doesn't Spring AMQP contain recovery/reconnect functionality?

Comment: @KrzysztofTomaszewski questions was related to shutting down container and starting it at some time later (not immediately).

Comment: This is clear for me. I was curious if this is something generally needed after experiencing a RabbitMQ broker failure?

Comment: @KrzysztofTomaszewski I needed this for partition change - to shut down simple message listener when some other component takes over the partition. In case there is failure - spring will reconnect automatically.

Comment: OK. I just have a case when the SimpleMesssageListenerContainer somehow silently (no ERROR log message) disconnected from the RabbitMQ broker and it was not receiving messages present in the queue. Still digging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `ApplicationEventPublisher` to the container; `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`s have a `fatal` boolean property.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So47357940Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47357940Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(AmqpAdmin admin) {
        return args -> admin.deleteQueue("so47357940");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so47357940")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    private final Map<SimpleMessageListenerContainer, AtomicBoolean> shuttingDown = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Bean
    public ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent> failures(AmqpAdmin admin,
            RabbitTemplate template) {
        return event -> {
            if (event.isFatal()) {
                SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) event.getSource();
                AtomicBoolean sd = this.shuttingDown.computeIfAbsent(container, v -> new AtomicBoolean());
                if (sd.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    System.out.println("RECREATING");
                    String[] qn = container.getQueueNames();
                    String q = qn[0];
                    admin.declareQueue(new Queue(q));
                    // better to use a shared exec
                    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                    exec.execute(() -> {
                        while (container.isRunning()) {
                            // should probably give up at some point
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            }
                        }
                        container.start();
                        template.convertAndSend("so47357940", "foo");
                        this.shuttingDown.remove(container);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("RECREATING_NOT");
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("NON_FATAL");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Here are the debug logs I get...

```
RECREATING
2017-11-17 17:38:53.893 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3)
2017-11-17 17:38:53.893 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Executing callback RabbitAdmin$$Lambda$144/1094003461 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473]
2017-11-17 17:38:53.893 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin         : declaring Queue 'so47357940'
2017-11-17 17:38:53.901 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Cancelling Consumer@3a813488: tags=[Cancelling Consumer@3a813488: tags=[{}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-11-17 17:38:53.901 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Closing Rabbit Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473]
2017-11-17 17:38:53.901 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Closing cached Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,2)
2017-11-17 17:38:53.903 ERROR 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
2017-11-17 17:38:53.903 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutting down Rabbit listener container
2017-11-17 17:38:53.903  INFO 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2017-11-17 17:38:53.903  INFO 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2017-11-17 17:38:54.003 DEBUG 42372 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Starting Rabbit listener container.
2017-11-17 17:38:54.004 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Starting consumer Consumer@3a2547b8: tags=[Starting consumer Consumer@3a2547b8: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-11-17 17:38:54.005 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Started on queue 'so47357940' with tag amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA: Consumer@3a2547b8: tags=[{amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA=so47357940}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-11-17 17:38:54.005 DEBUG 42372 --- [ool-1-thread-11] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : ConsumeOK : Consumer@3a2547b8: tags=[{amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA=so47357940}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-11-17 17:38:54.008 DEBUG 42372 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,4)
2017-11-17 17:38:54.008 DEBUG 42372 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Executing callback RabbitTemplate$$Lambda$146/1108520685 on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,4), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473]
2017-11-17 17:38:54.008 DEBUG 42372 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate      : Publishing message (Body:'foo' MessageProperties [headers=Publishing message (Body:'foo' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=3, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])on exchange [], routingKey = [so47357940], contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=3, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, deliveryTag=0])on exchange [], routingKey = [so47357940]
2017-11-17 17:38:54.012 DEBUG 42372 --- [ool-1-thread-12] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Storing delivery for Consumer@3a2547b8: tags=[{amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA=so47357940}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@48c9a496 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@3bdd3f4a [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 55473], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2017-11-17 17:38:54.012 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer   : Received message: (Body:'foo' MessageProperties [headers=Received message: (Body:'foo' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=so47357940, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA, consumerQueue=so47357940]), contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=so47357940, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA, consumerQueue=so47357940])
2017-11-17 17:38:54.015 DEBUG 42372 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] .a.r.l.a.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedRoutingKey=so47357940, amqp_contentEncoding=UTF-8, amqp_deliveryTag=1, amqp_consumerQueue=so47357940, amqp_redelivered=false, id=b614d9e6-1744-b600-7d86-ca9c51ad5844, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-3wMG_13-68ibLL05ir3ySA, contentType=text/plain, timestamp=1510958334014}]]
foo
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I already tried this approach, but have problem with multiple calls to this method - on failure there is at least 6 calls. Is it enough in this case just to recreate binding, and call start() on same ListenerContainer to make it work again?

Comment: Yes, you can restart a failed container if the fatal failure has been resolved.

Comment: Can you please check updated code in question above - seems like I still get only "Stopping container from aborted consumer" and no listeners, and the queue is actually recreated.

Comment: You can't do the stop/start on the listener thread; you also don't need to `stop()`; better to wait until the container stops itself. See my edit.

Comment: I am guessing it's a race condition and the `start()` doesn't do anything because the listener thread is still active. We should probably take a look at it to see if we can at least log an error if you attempt to `start()` the container on a stale listener thread [AMQP-785](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-785).

Comment: Just trying your code, but still cannot run. This is probably what you are talking about? I mean, I see that isRunning=false, but start does nothing.

Comment: Works for me - I added DEBUG logs so you can compare.

Comment: Works also for me with your original, but when I add concurrency `@RabbitListener(queues = "so47357940", concurrency = "4")` I have problem (start does not work).

Comment: Yeah - me too - definitely a race condition - if I add an additional `Thread.sleep(5000)` before `start()` it works. I changed that JIRA issue to a `Bug`.

Comment: Yes. OK, thanks then... That was the problem all along :) Suppose this is current workaround that is not 100% working fix, but good enough...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159306/discussion-between-bojanv55-and-gary-russell).